# SQL Server UK Date Corruption?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssms

I was looking up an earlier issue on SQL Server but I came across a sentence that I cannot find any additional information on.

On [this post](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?495512-RESOLVED-The-field-is-too-small-to-accept-the-amount-of-data-you-attempted-to-add), si_the_geek has said:

> "Using a UK format *will* damage your data and/or give you the wrong query results at some point."

The comment is nine years old at this point and I am curious if there is anything we still need to worry about with databases when it comes to dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still true for Access SQL.

If you want to insert 3rd June and do

```
INSERT INTO myTable (datefield) 
VALUES (#03/06/2016#)
```

Access will happily insert 6th March for you.

ISO format `'2016-06-03'` is safest.

Comment: Does this apply when using Access to insert 01/01/2016 into MS SQL Management Studio?

Or I be using 2016-01-01 from access to insert instead?

Comment: No. Datetime values carry no format. The format is for display only, or when you prefer to concatenate string expressions for fixed date values into an SQL string; and this you can avoid by using `DateSerial(2016, 06, 03)`.

Comment: @Jason: I don't know what you mean by "using Access to insert into MS SQL Management Studio?" - insert into a linked SQL Server table? Then yes. If you use SSMS to read an Access database, then probably not.